# How to pass a variable through .filter using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've managed to get a table from another page into a variable called *`res`*.

I need to pass this variable through a filter for *`search`*.

I'm getting the table row that corresponds by using **`.parents()`**.

This filter works when the table is on the same page as the jQuery, but not when using **`$.get()`**.

Below is my approach:

```
$.get('oncalltable.html', function(res) {

    var d = new Date();

    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    var oncalldate = ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
        ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + year % 100;

    var search = oncalldate;

    var todayoncall = $("span").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == search;
    }).parents('tr');

    console.log(oncalldate, res, todayoncall);

    $('.test span').append(todayoncall);

});
```

Comment: And what isn't working, did you check that the network request actually goes through?

Comment: `this` is different in the context of the `.filter()` function compared to the outer function. Are expecting the `this` from `$.get`?

Comment: Are there existing elements within `document` which have text which is equal to `search` variable? Can you include text value of `search` and `html` of `span` elements at Question? What is purpose of filtering all span elements, then appending existing `span` element to `.test span`? element?

Comment: What's missing here is a proper explanation of what you expect this code to do. Also we know nothing about what the page structure looks like...or the response structure

Comment: Do you get the expected data outputs in your console?

Answer (score 2):

JQuery selectors work against the DOM. oncalltable.html isn't in DOM, it's just text inside a variable that happens to resemble HTML.

I'm guessing that you expect your $("span") selector to see the contents of oncalltable.html. It won't because the `<span>` you're looking for (inside oncalltable.html) isn't in DOM.

If (and only if) you are supremely confident that the data you get in oncalltable.html is now and always will be completely trustworthy, you can add it to your DOM by loading that html into your page.

One way to do that would be to assign the contents of 'res' to the .innerHTML of some existing page element.
If you had (or decided to make) a hidden div to hold your data while it's parsed:

`<div id="whereResGoes" style="display:none"></div>`

then in the function you pass to $.get (just above the part where you use the $('span') selector), run

`$('#whereResGoes').html(res);`

Now it's loaded into your DOM and your $('span') selector can see it.

Note that since this approach makes oncalltable.html part of your page, it's like letting the author of oncalltable.html write anything they want on your page. If that page is ever compromised, yours will be too.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly the comment I needed to give me a good understanding of what jquery is all about.